# How are the 3 types of binary tree traversals (pre-order, in-order, post-order) used in real life?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I understand trees and tree-traversal, however, I have a hard time knowing which tree traversal is being used in real-life examples.

For example, do we navigate a file-system on a computer using pre-order traversal?
And when would we generally use one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a binary search tree then an in-order traversal can be used to show the elements contained in the data structure in sorted order. Seeing things in sorted order is generally useful. So if the tree has three nodes, A at the root and children B and C, and it's a binary search tree, you want:

```
B, A, C
```

If you have a file system with folders that contain folders and files, you might view this structure as a hierarchical directory structure. When you do this, you actually want the folder to be visited in the listing before its contents are, so you can align the folder to the left of its contents. The same tree as above interpreted as a directory structure probably should be viewed as this:

```
A
+- B
+- C
```

Not a bunch of examples come to mind for post-order traversals but one that does is reverse-polish notation. If you're making a calculator and are storing arithmetical expressions in a tree, then you could use a post-order traversal of that tree to get a sequence of terms in reverse-polish notation and use a known expression-evaluation algorithm that uses reverse polish notation. So if instead of A, B and C we have +, 3 and 4, then we might prefer to see a string like

```
3 4 +
```

An algorithm would interpret this as " pop 3 pop 4 pop +, push 3+4". Something like that.

Comment: Makes more sense now. Thanks for the help!